# How can i display portfolio images in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I've a sortable portfolio in my theme. And i want to display portfolio tags images in it. I find [this](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/) plugin for this. But i couldn't customize it very well.

Because i don't want to display posts' category images, i want to display portfolio's tags images in index. I think it will be clear with this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClgEA.jpg) I want to call this images, which you can see from the screenshot, in the index.

Here are my theme codes:

```
<?php

$query = ff_get_query_for_section();
if( !ff_archive_layout_type_test('portfolio', basename(__FILE__)) ){
    return false;
}

ff_require_portfolio_archive_helper_before();


$numberOfPosts = ( $query->get('number-of-posts') ) ;

?>
            <!-- Filter Section -->
            <section <?php ff_print_section_attributes($query->get('section-options-sortable section-options'), 'small-section'); //class="small-section bg-gray-lighter"?>>
                <div class="container relative">
                    <!-- Works Filter -->
                    <div class="container align-center">
                        <div class="works-filter  mb-0">

                        <a href="#" class="filter active" data-filter="*"><?php $query->printText('trans-all'); ?></a>
<?php
$portfolioTagsArray = array();
$portfolioTagsString = '';
$postCounter = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $postCounter++;
            $t = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'ff-portfolio-tag' );
            if( !empty($t) ) foreach ($t as $onePortfolioTag) {

                if( !isset($portfolioTagsArray[ $onePortfolioTag->slug ]) ) {
                    $portfolioTagsString .= '<a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".tag-'.esc_attr($onePortfolioTag->term_id).'">'.ff_wp_kses( $onePortfolioTag->name ).'</a>';
                }

                $portfolioTagsArray[ $onePortfolioTag->slug ] = $onePortfolioTag;
            }
            if( $numberOfPosts > 0 && $postCounter >= $numberOfPosts ) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    // Escaped HTML with tags
    echo $portfolioTagsString;

?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Works Filter -->

                </div>
            </section>
            <!--  End Filter Section -->


            <!-- Section -->
            <section <?php ff_print_section_attributes($query->get('section-options'), 'page-section');//class="page-section" id="portfolio"?>>
                <div class="container relative">

                    <!-- Works Grid -->
                    <ul class="works-grid work-grid-3 hover-color clearfix" id="work-grid">

 <?php
 $fwc = ffContainer::getInstance();
 $postMeta = $fwc->getDataStorageFactory()->createDataStorageWPPostMetas();
    rewind_posts();
    $postCounter = 0;
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            $postCounter++;
            $currentPostId = $post->ID;

            require dirname(__FILE__).'/portfolio-archive-one-post.php';

            if( $numberOfPosts > 0 && $postCounter >= $numberOfPosts  ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Works Grid -->

                    <?php
                    if( $query->get('show-pagination') ) {
                        ff_bigstream_print_pagination();
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- End Section -->
<?php
ff_require_portfolio_archive_helper_after();
```

And i tried to add this codes in this file:

```
   <?php foreach (wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'ff-portfolio-tag' ) as $cat) : ?>

<?php z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->term_id, 'ff-portfolio-tag'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But i couldn't be successfull. If you help, i would be grateful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[get_the_tags()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) an array of objects, one object for each tag assigned to the post. If this function is used in The Loop, then no ID need be passed.
This function does not display anything; you should access the objects and then echo or otherwise use the desired member variables.

> The following example displays the tag name of each tag assigned to
>   the post (this is like using [the_tags()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_tags), but without linking each tag
>   to the tag view, and using spaces instead of commas):

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand very well. I made this revision with considering your way but it's false. 
`<?php foreach (the_tags($onePortfolioTag as $tag) : ?>

<?php z_taxonomy_image($tag->tag_id); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->tag_id, 'ff-portfolio-tag'); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>`


@HassanALi

Comment: get_the_tags($post_id) use it this way you will the results .

Comment: `<?php foreach (get_the_tags($post_id) ?> 
<?php z_taxonomy_image($tag->tag_id); ?> 
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->tag_id, 'ff-portfolio-tag'); ?>">
<?php echo $tag->name; ?></a> 
<?php endforeach; ?>` Here is the latest code which i added my theme file. And i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' My php knowledge is not very well. And i don't think my codes are true. I took some codes from [here](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/) and tried to apply portfolio tags on it. Thanks for your patient @HassanALi

Comment: dnt need a forech it will return you a single object